# How can I insert elements in an array to a HTML document using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the elements of a list called "taskList" made up of values I get from the input elements.

Can anyone please help me, I don't understand why the elements from the list are not showing.

```js
var taskList = [];

var input = document.getElementById('takeInput');
var button = document.getElementById('addInput');

button.onclick = function(){
    var nHTML = '';
    var userEnteredText = input.value;
        taskList.push(userEnteredText);
    taskList.forEach(function(task){
        nHTML += '<li>'+task+'</li>';
    });
    document.getElementsByClassName('taskLists').innerHTML = '<ul>' + nHTML + '</ul>';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>To-Do List</header>
    <div class="taskAdder">
            <input id="takeInput" type="text" placeholder="Add your new To-Do">
            <button id="addInput" class="button" type="button" >➕</button>
    </div>
        <div class="taskLists">

        </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <span> You have <span class="pendingTasks"></span> tasks left </span> 
        <button type="button" class="button">Clear All</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried checking several times but nothing is updating in the HTML document

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't append to `innerHTML`, instead, use `createElement` to make the `li`, then set `innerHTML` of that new element to `input.value` and use `appendChild` to append it to the list

```js
var input = document.getElementById('takeInput');
var button = document.getElementById('addInput');
var tlist = document.getElementsByClassName('taskLists')[0];

button.onclick = function(){
    let e = document.createElement('li');
    e.innerHTML = input.value
    tlist.appendChild(e)
    
    // Optionally, clear the input field to prevent double adding the same task
    input.value = '';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>To-Do List</header>
    <div class="taskAdder">
            <input id="takeInput" type="text" placeholder="Add your new To-Do">
            <button id="addInput" class="button" type="button" >➕</button>
    </div>
        <div class="taskLists">

        </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <span> You have <span class="pendingTasks"></span> tasks left </span> 
        <button type="button" class="button">Clear All</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake was using `.getElementsByClassName` like it was one element only and not a list (don't ignore the ***s*** in elements!).

Anyway I slightly refactored your code to have better strategies for each of its goals and implemented also the logic for clearing the tasks list.

```js
var taskList = [];

var input = document.getElementById('takeInput');
var buttonAdd = document.getElementById('addInput');
var buttonClear = document.getElementById('clearInput');
var tasksList = document.getElementById('tasksList');

buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{  
  addTask(input.value);  
});

buttonClear.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{  
  tasksList = [];
  document.querySelector('#tasksList ul').remove();
});

function addTask(value){
  if(taskList.length == 0){
    document.getElementById('tasksList').append( document.createElement('ul') );
  }
  taskList.push(value);
  const newLI = document.createElement('li');
  newLI.innerText = value;
  document.querySelector('#tasksList ul').append(newLI);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  
    <header>To-Do List</header>
    
    <div class="taskAdder">
      <input id="takeInput" type="text" placeholder="Add your new To-Do">
      <button id="addInput" class="button" type="button">➕</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tasksList">
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
      <span> You have <span class="pendingTasks"></span> tasks left </span>
      <button id="clearInput" type="button" class="button">Clear All</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just needed to use an ID on the tasklist.

getElementsByClassName needs an index, making your question a dupe of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return):

`document.getElementsByClassName('taskLists')[0].innerHTML`

That said, here is a full version using recommended eventListener and IDs where relevant.

```js
let tasks = [];
const taskList = document.getElementById('taskLists') 
const input = document.getElementById('takeInput');
const add = document.getElementById('addInput');
const pendingTasks = document.getElementById('pendingTasks');
const clear = document.getElementById('clear');

const showTasks = () => {
  taskList.innerHTML = `<ul>${tasks.map(task => `<li>${task}</li>`).join('')}</ul>`;
  pendingTasks.textContent = `${tasks.length} task${tasks.length != 1 ? "s" : ""}`;
};  
add.addEventListener('click', ()  => {
  var userEnteredText = input.value; 
  tasks.push(userEnteredText);
  showTasks();
});

clear.addEventListener('click', ()  => {
  tasks = [];
  showTasks();
});

taskList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('li');
  if (!tgt) return; // not a task
  const task = tgt.textContent;
  tgt.remove()
  tasks = tasks.filter(currentTask => currentTask != task); // remove from list
  showTasks()
});
showTasks(); //init
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>To-Do List</header>
  <div class="taskAdder">
    <input id="takeInput" type="text" placeholder="Add your new To-Do">
    <button id="addInput" class="button" type="button">➕</button>
  </div>
  <div id="taskLists"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <span> You have <span id="pendingTasks"></span> left </span>
    <button type="button" id="clear">Clear All</button>
  </div>
</div>
```